# tensorflow-gpu 2.3 install with cuda and cudnn can't detect GPU?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a problem about using GPU in tensorflow
I'm using RTX2060

I'm following from this tutorial [Solution to TensorFlow 2 not using GPU](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/solution-to-tensorflow-2-not-using-gpu-119fb3e04daa)

I have installed

cudatoolkit = 10.2.89

cudnn = 7.6.5

tensorflow-gpu = 2.3.0

but when i check in python with

`print("Num GPUs Available: ", len(tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')))`

it turn out that my GPU num is 0

I haved try to find the solution all over the internet but still can't fixed it.

Please help, Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

So that guide is not adequate for setting up tensorflow with a GPU; for example, here's a random guide (of which there are many) explaining some of the components missing.  Notice the sections dealing with the CUDA driver, an appropriate GPU driver version, specific linux distro (Ubuntu 20.04), etc.:

[random example of how to set up tensorlfow for use with a GPU](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/installing-tensorflow-with-cuda-cudnn-gpu-support-on-ubuntu-20-04-f6f67745750a)

I have no idea if this is a good guide or if it works at all, but I just wanted to point out some important missing components of the guide you are using.

So you have to set up the CUDA driver (I noticed that you don't mention a CUDA driver version at all) with the appropriate GPU drivers and the appropriate linux distribution (I have never set up CUDA on Windows so idk about that) in order for tensorflow to be able to recognize your GPU.

Comment: Actually I think cudatoolkit is the same of Cuda

Comment: There's the CUDA driver and the CUDA tool kit, they are not the same thing.  The CUDA driver version has to be greater than or equal to the CUDA toolkit version.  The tool kit usually contains a driver, but you will be better off installing the specific CUDA driver version that will work with you system.

Comment: Oh sorry. I also have install cuda driver 10.2 too.

Comment: Are you using linux, if so you might want to take a look here:https://docs.nvidia.com/deploy/cuda-compatibility/index.html.  You're going to need a GPU driver that meets the requirment: >= 440.33.  If you are on windows you can look here:https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-microsoft-windows/index.html